# InvalidConfigurationException with Doctrine and result_cache_driver

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm attempting to include some sort of result caching on Doctrine. However, I keep coming up against this error:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options
>   "result_cache_driver" under "doctrine.orm"

All I have done is add result_cache_driver: array like so:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    result_cache_driver: array
```

Any ideas? Do I need to install some separate Doctrine bundle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager:  ~
    auto_generate_proxy_classes:  %kernel.debug%
    proxy_dir:  %kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies
    proxy_namespace:  Proxies
    entity_managers:
        # A collection of different named entity managers (e.g. some_em, another_em)
        some_em:
            # ...
            result_cache_driver:
                type: array # Required
```